# SQL behind the reports changes, but recordset returned does not, is that a problem?

Tags: t-sql, jasper-reports

I'm a SQL Server database engineer charged with optimizing SQL behind Jasper reports.  If I optimize the T-SQL, but return the record set with the exact same fields, in the exact same order, with the exact same formats as before, will that be an issue for Jasper Reports?

What I mean by this is that a particular Jasper Report operations with a particular SQL Statement, bound by .  That SQL statement returns a certain set of fields, in a certain order, with certain formats.

If I maintain those, but change (optimize) the SQL Statement that returns those fields, will that be an issue?

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: I'm not sure what's unclear about it.  Could you be more specific?